# How to create new Tags in Sharepoint forum

Tags: support

I am trying to create new tags for the SharePoint 2013 Services Applications but i could not find the way, from where i can create it. could you please help me.
i want create tags for the following services.

PowerPoint Automation Services
Visio Graphics Service
Machine Translation Service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a tag, you need to have 300 reputation (https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/privileges).

If you have enough reputation it is as simple as writing in a new tag when you create or edit a question.

Comment: i have more than 300 reputation but still not able to create new.

Comment: Are you adding the tag on a question? Because that is how you need to do it @WaqasSarwarMCSE